# Setting PYTHONPATH on Windows under Anaconda without elevated privileges

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, anaconda, pythonpath

I have a Windows 7 machine with a 32-bit install of anaconda, installed for the local user. The install works as expected: it allows me to run python and pip from the command line, switch environments, etc.

I also have a library of code that I wrote sitting in My Documents. I would like to add an entry like `C:\Users\username\Documents\MyLib` to my `PYTHONPATH`. This would normally not be an issue, but I do not have the elevated privileges that this (work-issued) computer requires to modify environment variables through the Windows UI.

I am looking for a way to set PYTHONPATH. I only need it to work within the anaconda environment (i.e., I just want to be able to import my library using that particular interpreter). Solutions using `sys.path.append` within my scripts are not acceptable. I am, however, OK with doing `sys.path.append` in some script that will be executed automatically whenever I run `python myscript.py`.

I suspect that there is a way to get around the privilege restrictions imposed through the Windows UI though, because running `conda info -a` shows that the Anaconda installer was able to insert items into the `PATH`, specifically, `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin;...`.

Comment: I will try to go through the user accounts and see what happens. Thanks for that tip. As far as using a batch script goes, I don't know how to get it to run automatically before any Python code executes.'

Comment: @eryksun. `cmd.exe`

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I use both cmd and spyder mostly, but also  IPython and bash. However, your solution to go through the user account settings worked perfectly. Could you write an answer based on that (perhaps include the info about writing a replacement for cmd for future readers as well)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Control Panel window for modifying user accounts, there should be an option to change the environment variables just for the current user. It's broken on some versions of Windows, but if it works it's the simplest option.

If that doesn't work, the next simplest option is to use setx.exe in a command prompt. It defaults to the current user. For example:

```
setx.exe PYTHONPATH "C:\Users\username\Documents\MyLib"
```

You can also use reg.exe to set the variable manually in the registry. But unlike the above options, this doesn't broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to top-level windows. When Explorer sees that message it reloads its environment from the registry. Without it, you'll have to log off and back on again to see the updated environment variable. With that said, here's an example command using reg.exe:

```
reg.exe add HKCU\Environment /f /v PYTHONPATH /d "C:\Users\username\Documents\MyLib"
```

---

I'm not a fan of permanently setting `PYTHONPATH` because the same variable gets used by every version of Python. I'd rather create a shortcut to a batch script that configures the environment the way I need it for a specific task. For example:

```batch
@echo off
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\username\Documents\MyLib
C:\Users\username\Documents\MyEnv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Create a shortcut to this batch script. Then right-click the shortcut and select "Properties". Modify the target to run `cmd.exe /k "path\to\the\script.bat"`.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you about setting environment variables, but for this particular lab machine, everything runs off a single Python 3 interpreter. It is unlikely that we will start using Py2, even if we need environments with different library configurations.

Answer (score 11):

Since you said, you mostly use Spyder, the following might be useful:

Spyder offers the option to manage PYTHONPATH through an integrated manager.

[image]